# Why do I see Partial results with attoparsec when I expect to see Failure?

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I'm a little confused by this behaviour of attoparsec.

```
$ ghci
> :m Data.Attoparsec.Text
> :m + Data.Text
> parse (string (pack "module")) (pack "mox")
Partial _
> parse (string (pack "module")) (pack "moxxxx")
Fail "moxxxx" [] "Failed reading: takeWith"
>
```

Why do I need addition characters present to trigger the Fail?

Shouldn't it Fail as soon as the first "x" is encountered?

Comment: For future reference, I opened a ticket and the Attoparsec maintainer fixed this bug: https://github.com/bos/attoparsec/issues/97

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an implementation detail, a `string` parser doesn't finish before it knows whether there is enough input remaining for it to possibly succeed. It's a consequence of the all-or-nothing behaviour of these parsers (which, I think, is generally good for performance).

```
string :: Text -> Parser Text
string s = takeWith (T.length s) (==s)
```

`string s` tries to take `length s` units of `Text`, and then compare them with `s`.

```
takeWith :: Int -> (Text -> Bool) -> Parser Text
takeWith n p = do
  s <- ensure n
  let h = unsafeTake n s
      t = unsafeDrop n s
  if p h
    then put t >> return h
    else fail "takeWith"
```

`takeWith n p` first tries to ensure that `n` units of `Text` are available, and

```
ensure :: Int -> Parser Text
ensure !n = T.Parser $ \i0 a0 m0 kf ks ->
    if lengthAtLeast (unI i0) n
    then ks i0 a0 m0 (unI i0)
    else runParser (demandInput >> go n) i0 a0 m0 kf ks
  where
    go n' = T.Parser $ \i0 a0 m0 kf ks ->
        if lengthAtLeast (unI i0) n'
        then ks i0 a0 m0 (unI i0)
        else runParser (demandInput >> go n') i0 a0 m0 kf ks
```

`ensure n` creates a continuation asking for more <del>gruel</del> input (a `Partial` result) if it doesn't find enough input immediately.

You can get a failure with

```
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.Text Data.Text> parseOnly (string (pack "module")) (pack "mox")
Left "not enough input"
```

telling the parser up front that it won't get any more input (then the `demandInput` from `ensure` makes it fail), or later

```
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.Text Data.Text> parse (string (pack "module")) (pack "mox")
Partial _
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.Text Data.Text> feed it (pack "")
Fail "mox" ["demandInput"] "not enough input"
```

by telling the `Partial` result that that was it, feeding it an empty `Text`.

Comment: Thanks - this make sense after your explanation.