# Attoparsec atEnd behavior

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I am trying to write a bytestring parser with Attoparsec and I've been running into some puzzling behavior with the [`atEnd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.12.1.3/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#v:atEnd) function. Just playing around, I tried to parse the empty bytestring with `atEnd` to see if it would return `True`, but instead it returns a partial parse. Is this expected? Can someone quickly explain the behavior of the `atEnd` function?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287237/why-do-i-see-partial-results-with-attoparsec-when-i-expect-to-see-failure Try using `parseOnly` when testing it in GHCi maybe.

Comment: @FrankWang Could we close this question as a duplicate of the one danem linked to in his/her comment?